# Nesting HTML Tables

Tags: html

I am currently working on a html table where B and C tiles of the table in attached screenshot to be merged into one single tile. 
Please find attached the screenshot and the code. I have attached the code as stackoverflow snippet, please check. Can anybody here help me please on this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

```html
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: auto; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: white; TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-TOP: 4px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(139,198,100)" colSpan=2>
        <FONT size=2 style="FONT-SIZE: 18px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: white">
          <STRONG><FONT color=#ffffff size=2>Select a Study:</FONT></STRONG>
        </FONT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
<TABLE style="HEIGHT: 35%; WIDTH: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: auto; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=2>
          <STRONG><FONT size=4>A</FONT> <BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <FONT size=4>
          <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=cc25934ac4de4386ad7ce45aed675335 /></STRONG>
        </FONT>
      </TD>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=4>
          <STRONG>D<BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=8da4f7a82bbe46cd8eafbbcec7189995 /></STRONG>
      </TD>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; HEIGHT: 300%; WIDTH: 25%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=4>
          <STRONG>E<BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=eb17e9a209314097b6519af8e8adfe5b /></STRONG>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>


<TABLE style="HEIGHT: 30%; WIDTH: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: auto; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=2>
          <STRONG><FONT size=4>B*</FONT> <BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <FONT size=4>
          <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=cc25934ac4de4386ad7ce45aed675335 /></STRONG>
        </FONT>
      </TD>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=4>
          <STRONG>F<BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=8da4f7a82bbe46cd8eafbbcec7189995 /></STRONG>
      </TD>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; HEIGHT: 300%; WIDTH: 25%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=4>
          <STRONG>G<BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=eb17e9a209314097b6519af8e8adfe5b /></STRONG>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>



<TABLE style="HEIGHT: 35%; WIDTH: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: auto; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=2>
          <STRONG><FONT size=4>C*</FONT> <BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <FONT size=4>
          <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=cc25934ac4de4386ad7ce45aed675335 /></STRONG>
        </FONT>
      </TD>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=4>
          <STRONG>H<BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=8da4f7a82bbe46cd8eafbbcec7189995 /></STRONG>
      </TD>
      <TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; HEIGHT: 300%; WIDTH: 25%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px">
        <FONT color=#007cc2 size=4>
          <STRONG>I<BR></STRONG>
        </FONT>
        <STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=eb17e9a209314097b6519af8e8adfe5b /></STRONG>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 2):

You can combine into one table and use rowspan = "2"

```html
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: auto; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: white; TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-TOP: 4px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(139,198,100)" colSpan=2><FONT size=2 style="FONT-SIZE: 18px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: white"><STRONG><FONT color=#ffffff size=2>Select a Study:</FONT></STRONG></FONT></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>

<TABLE style="HEIGHT: 35%; WIDTH: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: auto; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0>
<TR>
<TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=2><STRONG><FONT size=4>A</FONT> <BR></STRONG></FONT><FONT size=4><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=cc25934ac4de4386ad7ce45aed675335 /></STRONG></FONT></TD>
<TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=4><STRONG>D<BR></STRONG></FONT><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=8da4f7a82bbe46cd8eafbbcec7189995 /></STRONG></TD>
<TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; HEIGHT: 300%; WIDTH: 25%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=4><STRONG>E<BR></STRONG></FONT><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=eb17e9a209314097b6519af8e8adfe5b /></STRONG></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD rowspan="2" style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=2><STRONG><FONT size=4>B*</FONT> <BR></STRONG></FONT><FONT size=4><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=cc25934ac4de4386ad7ce45aed675335 /></STRONG></FONT></TD>
<TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=4><STRONG>F<BR></STRONG></FONT><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=8da4f7a82bbe46cd8eafbbcec7189995 /></STRONG></TD>
<TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; HEIGHT: 300%; WIDTH: 25%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=4><STRONG>G<BR></STRONG></FONT><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=eb17e9a209314097b6519af8e8adfe5b /></STRONG></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; WIDTH: 30%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=4><STRONG>H<BR></STRONG></FONT><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=8da4f7a82bbe46cd8eafbbcec7189995 /></STRONG></TD>
<TD style="BORDER-TOP: rgb(247,243,247) 0pt solid; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; HEIGHT: 300%; WIDTH: 25%; BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 6px; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 6px; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(247,243,247) 2px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px"><FONT color=#007cc2 size=4><STRONG>I<BR></STRONG></FONT><STRONG><SPOTFIRECONTROL id=eb17e9a209314097b6519af8e8adfe5b /></STRONG></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```